# Python function to mirror an image vertically from R to L

Tags: python, function, mirror

I am trying to write a python function to mirror the right half of a picture to the left half.  So far I have this code but it works in the opposite way (it mirrors from L to R)  I know it must be a few simple changes, but I just seem to have a block now.  Any help appreciated.

```
def mirrorVertical(source):
  mirrorPoint = getWidth(source) / 2
  width = getWidth(source)
  for y in range(0,getHeight(source)):
    for x in range(0,mirrorPoint):
      leftPixel = getPixel(source,x,y)
      rightPixel = getPixel(source,width - x - 1,y)
      color = getColor(leftPixel)
      setColor(rightPixel,color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  color = getColor(rightPixel)
  setColor(leftPixel,color)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are iterating from the top left corner to the middle, instead of the right corner to the middle. Might want to try range(getWidth(), mirrorPoint) for x and leave y the same.

Answer (score 0):

Before changing the color of the `rightPixel`, you should save this color to somewhere in order to set it on the `leftPixel`.

Something like

```
color_left = getColor(leftPixel)
color_right = getColor(rightPixel)
setColor(leftPixel, color_right)
setColor(rightPixel, color_left)
```

should do the trick.